# bootstrap dropdown menu active class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i am trying to create a nav bar by using bootstrap but when I redirect active class to dropdown menu, all the sub menus receive active class. I only want Project section to use active class

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" 
                 data-target="#example-navbar-collapse">
                 <span class="sr-only"></span>
                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="example-navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
             <li><a href="index.html">About</a></li>
             <li class="dropdown active">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                   Project <b class="caret"></b>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                   <li><a href="project.html">AAAA</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">BBB</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">CCC</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">DDD</a></li>
                </ul>
             </li>
             <li><a href="team.html">Team</a></li>
             <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
       </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a { //styles here for active li }` to target the active `<li>` only, like this:

```css
.dropdown-menu {
  display: block !important;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a {
  color: blue !important;
  background: red !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#example-navbar-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="example-navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="index.html">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown active">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                   Project <b class="caret"></b>
                </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="project.html">AAAA</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">BBB</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">CCC</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">DDD</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="team.html">Team</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't see the css code... you need to add an `>` between `li` and `ul`

```
li > ul
```